# Properly check health of Mac SSD

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, battery

I got an old Macbook pro (2017, i5, 13") that has a faulty battery. That shows in two ways:

1. I get regular problems with booting up. I will refuse to do so, showing me an error code ("apple.com/support 2006F") that apparently is linked to a faulty disk (?).
2. The system tells me that servicing the battery would be recommended ("The battery's capacity is significantly reduced")

Now, replacing the battery is quite pricey, but still reasonable compared to buying new. Anyhow, as the SSD cant be replaced, "repairing" the SSD would be completely unreasonable.

Running DiskUtility gives you a rough assessment if everything is ok with the disk and/or partition. Looks pretty superficial to me though. (i.e. `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0` will check the partition table and that's about it). The Check doesn't show any errors.

So, my question here is: How to make sure that the SSD is *NOT* faulty (too), i.e. the investment in a new battery is worth the hassle? In other words: How to run a proper check on the SSD?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some 2017 MBPs do have a removable SSD module, so just be certain which type your Mac is.

Error 2006F seems to indicate that Internet Recovery is not working. That suggests there isn't a valid OS on the disk. Most solutions suggest reseting the PRAM and/or SMC.

Internet Recovery normally kicks in only when there is no valid Recovery Partition on the SSD.

You could also try preparing an OS installer on an external drive, if you have access to another Mac. If you can get a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adaptor, it's possible that connecting with Ethernet cable to the router will give you a connection.

Replacing the battery would normally entail a visit to an Apple Store or other authorised repair shop. They would also be able to diagnose any problem with the SSD, and you could then decide whether spending money on this Mac is worthwhile or not.

Comment: That's interesting, as there is a working Mac OS X (Ventura) running on that machine. I also tried resetting the PRAM without any changes to the problem.

Comment: Regarding to the model, its a Macbook Pro 13" 2017 with an i5

Comment: So, sometimes it boots up to Ventura, and sometimes it doesn't, with the error? That does suggest some problem. Take it to an Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

> How to run a proper check on the SSD?

[DriveDX](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) should be able to help you out. There's a free, time-limited trial. The information provided by the trial version is no different to the paid version.